# Ensuring Run Order of FOR Loop with a GCD Thread ? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I have a serial queue which contains two methods which load and image and then, once completed, add the image to the subview. The images are in a NSMutableArray so I am iterating over a For loop to load them in as follows :

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL); 
for (int i =0; i<=[pictureThumbnailArray count]-1; i++) {
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSLog(@"Thumbnail count is %d", [pictureThumbnailArray count]);

        finishedImage = [self setImage:[pictureThumbnailArray objectAtIndex:i]:i];

        if (finishedImage !=nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        [self.view addSubview:finishedImage];
    });

        }
    });
                   }
```

The problem is that the images seem to be loaded randomly. What I want to achieve is that each iteration of the For loop runs and completes before the next iteration starts - that way the images should load in the same way each time.

Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this - I am thinking I may need to synchronise the setImage method (first method in queue) ?

Changed To :

```
for (int i =0; i<=[pictureThumbnailArray count]-1; i++) {

    NSLog(@"Thumbnail count is %d", [pictureThumbnailArray count]);

        finishedImage = [self setImage:[pictureThumbnailArray objectAtIndex:i]:i];

        if (finishedImage !=nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        [self.view addSubview:finishedImage];
    });

        }
                   }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some other problem - perhaps your image array is not in the order you think it is. Both queue and mainQueue are serial queues. To verify this I just did a quick test and got the  log messages in the expected order. I suggest you try adding log messages or so to figure out why the order is not as you expect:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

static dispatch_queue_t queue;
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);

    for (int i =0; i<=20; i++) {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                NSLog(@"Image %d", i);
            });
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped - the problem was nothing to do with the code, but rather that I was calling it twice due to my rotation methods...as Mr Simpson would say : doh.

Answer (score 0):

What if we do the things simpler without GCD? I suggest get rid of it and use NSURLConnectionDelegate methods.

This method downloads next image:

```
-(void)startDownload
{
    if (index < URLs.count)
    {
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLs[index]];
        _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL] delegate:self];
    }
}
```

The `connectionDidFinishLoading:` delegate method places the image to the view and starts next download.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:_data];
    _data = nil;
    _connection = nil;
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:100+index];
    imageView.image = image;
    index++;
    [self startDownload];
}
```

Here is the complete example: https://github.com/obrizan/TestImageDownload The images rather big so give some time to load them.